# Passing variables to fpdf

Tags: pdf, fpdf

I have a problem with passing variables to fpdf. First script is getting post text sent to filtering class, the class is returning filtered POST-s as a 2 element array. First script looks like this:

```
include('service.php');
include('pdf.php');

    $pdf_filter = new Pdf_filter;
    $filter = $pdf_filter->pdfFilter();
    var_dump($filter);
    extract($filter);
```

I'm extracting `$filter` array to get variables from it (filtering script is creating variables of the POST that are sent and I can `echo` them so I don't know if this is even necessary).

The second script looks like this:

```
require('E:\Xampp\php\fpdf181\fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(195,5, $tytul, 0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(195,5, $petycja, 0,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: tytul in E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\pdf.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: petycja in E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\pdf.php on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in E:\Xampp\php\fpdf181\fpdf.php:271 
Stack trace: #0 E:\Xampp\php\fpdf181\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') 
#1 E:\Xampp\php\fpdf181\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() 
#2 E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\pdf.php(12): FPDF->Output() 
#3 E:\Xampp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\test.php(3): include('E:\\Xampp\\htdocs...') 
#4 {main} thrown in E:\Xampp\php\fpdf181\fpdf.php on line 271
```

How should I pass the variables? Interesting: it works if I use the unfiltered `$_POST` with the following code:

```
require('E:\Xampp\php\fpdf181\fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(195,5, $_POST['tytul'], 0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(195,5, $_POST['petycja'], 0,1,'C');
$pdf->Output();
```

EDIT: I will post the initial form and filtering function:
Form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    Wpisz tytuł petycji (35 znaków):<br>
        <input type="text" name="tytul" maxlength="35" size="35" placeholder="Tytuł petycji" required><br>
    Wpisz treść petycji (500 znaków):<br>
        <textarea name="petycja" maxlength="500" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Treść petycji" required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Napisz petycje">        
    </form>
```

Filtering function:

```
class Pdf_filter{
    protected $title;
    protected $text;
        public function pdfFilter(){
            if (isset($_POST)){

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {

            $filterVal = strip_tags($val);
            $filterVal = htmlspecialchars($filterVal);
            $filterVal = stripslashes($filterVal);
            $filterVal = str_replace("\\", "", $filterVal);

            $filter = array($key => $filterVal);
                foreach ($filter as $key => $val) {
                    echo "[$$key]";
                    echo "$val<br>";
                    ${$key} = $val;
                    }
            }
        if(!preg_match("/^[\sa-zA-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż0-9-_,.:\'?()]+$/", $tytul)){
            echo "Niedozwolone znaki $tytul!";
            exit();
            }
            elseif(!preg_match("/^[\sa-zA-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż0-9-_,.:\'?()]+$/", $petycja)){
                echo "Niedozwolone znaki $petycja!";
                exit();
            }
            else{
                return $filter = array('tytul'=>$tytul,'petycja'=>$petycja);
            }
    }
    else{
        echo "Proszę wypełnić wszytskie pola!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using `$tytul = $_POST['tytul'];` in the second script? Or is that being set in some other script that isn't given? Without knowing how they are being set, I can't really give you a good answer but it is likely that you are using class variables that you aren't using correctly.

Comment: I think you might be right about "using class variables" not correctly. But whole script goes like this: 2 text forms (tytul i petycja) passed by $_POST to first script -> filtering $_POST -> returning filtered variables back to first script -> passing variables to second script. If you need any more code let me know what to write.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see how the variables are being set. So if you would provide that code and how that file is linked ( included / required ).

Comment: @TylerChristian done. I posted form and filtering function.

Comment: Ok, I'm on to something. I know that I'm passing variables wrongly. I know now that I should create '__construct()' if I want to pass variable to class but it gets harder when I need to do this with fpdf... no idea how.

Comment: I think it's more of an issue with how you are accessing the class variables and how they are being set. Do some research in setting and using class variables in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am dumb. The problem was related with class variables. Code that happened to work for me:

```
class Pdf extends FPDF{
        protected $filter;
        protected $tytul;
        protected $petycja;
        public function __construct($filter){
            $this->filter = extract($filter);
            $this->tytul = $tytul;
            $this->petycja = $petycja;
        }
        public function tytul(){
            return $this->tytul;
        }
        public function petycja(){
            return $this->petycja;
        }
        public function dokument(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->AddPage();
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            $this->Cell(195,5, $this->tytul, 0,1,'C');
            $this->Cell(195,5, $this->petycja, 0,1,'C');
            $this->Output();
        }
}
```

Now I need to think of a way to display polish symbols in fpdf and line breaks (but that maybe done with text editor isntead of just textbox).